# Reverse proxy in front of .NET core app when deploying a custom docker container to App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I'm planning to deploy my .NET core application as custom docker container to Azure App Service but have a couple of questions regarding the load balancer.

I have read in the documentation that it is a good idea to place a reverse proxy in front of the Kestrel webserver. Is it recommended to create a multi docker container that has a Nginx reverse proxy in front of the webserver instead of a single container when deploying to App Service? Or does the load balancer already deal with this?

Comment: Just to clarify, that's one container that you want to deploy multiple times. Right?

Comment: @CSharpRocks That is correct, it is one container that has .NET core and Angular combined that I would like to be able to scale out on Azure App Service.

Comment: What did you end up doing with this, I was under the impression that the Azure App Service was acting like a reverse proxy since it can handle authentication and the SSL certificates.